# How to pass nested json object to Capacitor plugin?

Tags: swift, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I want to pass a nested Json Object from `JavaScript` context to a Capacitor plugin.
No nested objects are working. When nested, I'm struggling with the `JSValue` that I cannot cast into a dictionary.

```
@objc(MyPlugin)
public class MyPlugin: CAPPlugin {

    @objc func start(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        let fooCAP: JSObject = call.getObject("foo")!

        let foo: Foo = // ?
    }
}


public struct Foo: Decodable {
    let bar: Bar
}

public struct Bar: Decodable {
    let color: String
}
```

I can get the bar value with `fooCAP["bar"]`, but I can't get the color value with `fooCAP["bar"]["color"]` because `fooCAP["bar"]` is of type JSValue.

The documentation says, I should use `.toDictionary()`, but this function doesn't exist.

How can I convert the `JSObject` into my struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```swift
if let bar = fooCAP["bar"] as? JSObject {
    if let color = bar["color"] as? String {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Here you can find another [example](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase/blob/57ae20929918bab6915536843109424a80495b42/packages/authentication/ios/Plugin/FirebaseAuthenticationPlugin.swift#L230) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! 
`bar` works. `color` seems not to be a String. The example you added additionally should actually work like that. I'm not sure, what I am doing wrong 

Comment: I updated my example. There was an error.

Comment: This works! I thought the old one included some kind of magic :D Thank you!